# Bad input shape with sklearn make_scorer needs_proba=True

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The code below works fine with:
`scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_score)`

but gives "ValueError: bad input shape" with:
`scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, needs_proba = True)`

The code is:
`clf = GaussianNB()
cv = ShuffleSplit(features.shape[0], n_iter = 10, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, needs_proba = True)
score = cross_val_score(clf, features, labels, cv=cv, scoring=scorer)`

How would I get around this error so the score is based on probability estimates?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using one of the default scoring metrics you don't need to pass a callable to `cross_val_score`, you can just, you can just call it with the name of the metric you're using:

```
score = cross_val_score(clf, features, labels, cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc_score')
```

Comment: Thank you @maxymoo!  `score = cross_val_score(clf, features, labels, cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc')`  worked nicely.